# not able to acces private method through privilaged methods in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

Error : undefined error in console, while trying to print age function

```js
var Person = function( myName, myProfession, myage ){
        this.name = myName;  // Public Variable 
        this.profession = myProfession;
        var age = myage;  // Private Variable 
        this.myAge = function(){  // Privilaged Method
            return this.age;
        };
        };
      var syed = new Person('syed azam','developer',20);
      console.log(syed + "works fine");
      console.log(syed.myAge());
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

What is `this.age`? You did not encapsulate it correctly:

```
this.myAge = function(){
    return myage;
};
```

Note that you don't have to use `var age = myage;`. **[DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/q4t3twjf/1/)**

Comment: Thanks, i am trying to access private variable through privileged method, i think you have removed private variable..

Comment: @undefined: And this answer shows you the correct way to do it. There is no `this.age` which is why you get `undefined`. You need to declare `age` with `var` for it to be private and then just return `age`

Comment: @MattBurland : +1 Super, thanks gotcha, my bad mistakenly i added this.age inside the function.

Comment: @MattBurland I've reverted your edit. Why do you want to change it to `age`? I've explained it in the last sentence.

Comment: @freakish: Sorry about that. I did notice that, but it wouldn't let me rollback my own edit. I do think it's probably not a great idea to have both `myage` and `this.myage` however since it's pretty hard to read.